# Chunked Transfer Encoding problem with Apache Abdera

Tags: http, multipart, atom-feed, transfer-encoding, apache-abdera

I'm using Apache Abdera to POST atom multipart data to my server, and am having some odd problems that I can't pin down.

It looks like an issue with chunked transfer encoding, but I'm insufficiently experienced to be certain.  The problem manifests as the server throwing an error indicating that the request I sent it contains only one mime part, not two as required.  I attached Wireshark to the interface and captured the conversation, and it went like this:

```
POST /sss/col-uri/2ee98ea1-f9ad-4f01-9b1c-cfa3c4a6dc3c HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Expect: 100-continue
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="1306399868259";type="application/atom+xml;type=entry"
```

The server's response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

My client continues:

```
198
--1306399868259
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="atom"

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">Richard Woz Ere</title><bibliographicCitation xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">this is my citation</bibliographicCitation><content type="application/zip" src="cid:48bd9436-e8b6-4f68-aa83-5c88eda52fd4" /></entry>
0

b0e9

--1306399868259
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="payload"; filename="example.zip"
Content-ID: <48bd9436-e8b6-4f68-aa83-5c88eda52fd4>
Packaging: http://purl.org/net/sword/package/SimpleZip
```

And at this point the server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 26 May 2011 08:51:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.1
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Indicating the error (which is well understood).  My server goes on to stream a pile of base64 encoded bits onto the output stream, but in the mean time the server is not listening, it has already decided that the request was erroneous.

Unfortunately, I'm not in charge of the HTTP layer - this is all handled by Abdera using Apache httpclient.  My code that does this looks like this:

```
client.execute("POST", url.toString(), new SWORDMultipartRequestEntity(deposit), options);
```

Here, the SWORDMultipartRequestEntity is a copy of the standard Abdera MultipartRequestEntity class, with a few extra headers thrown in (see, for example, Packaging in the above snippet); the "deposit" argument is just an object holding the atom part and the inputstream.

When attaching a debugger I get to this line of code fine, and then it disappears into a rat hole and then I get this error back.

Any hints or tips?  I've pretty much exhausted my angles of attack!

The only thing that stands out for me is that immediately after the atom:entry document, there is a newline with "0" on it alone, which appears to be chunked transfer encoding speak for "I'm finished".  Not sure how it got there, or whether it really has any effect.  Help much appreciated.

Cheers,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The lonely `0` may indeed be a problem. My uninformed guess is that it results from some call to `flush()`, which then writes the whole buffer as another HTTP chunk. Unfortunately at the point where `flush` is called, the buffer had already been flushed and its size is therefore zero. So the `HttpChunkedOutputFilter` (or however it is called) should be taught than an empty buffer does not need to be flushed.

[update:] You should set a breakpoint in the `ChunkedOutputStream` class, especially the `flush` method. I just looked at its code and it seems to be ok, but maybe I missed something.